# Project won't compile in IntelliJ IDEA after adding Maven support because of complaints about the JDK version

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntellJ 14.1.4 Community Edition

My project compiled fine before (I have it set up to use the Eclipse compiler)

But I tried to Mavenize it...

I added Maven via the Add Framework | Maven command

Now my problem is (still using the Eclipse Compiler)...

It gives me error messages like:

Error:(21, 78) java: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Which leads me to suspect that it is not compiling to 1.8

However, I didn't change anything other than Mavenizing it

The Project SDK in IDEA is set to use 1.8

I did notice some setting about bytecode being 1.5.. but i tried to change that to 1.8 but still get this error message.

Anyone have any clue what's going on?

Comment: You need to configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` to use 1.8 source and target.

Comment: there's no way it can just use the default JDK?

Comment: how do I know what <version> to use for maven-compiler-plugin ?

Comment: Maven defaults to Java 1.5, this is regardless of the IDE used. You can see the latest version of a Maven plugin by looking at their [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/): this is 3.3 for `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

this was essentially the correct advice of course - in the comments, however I had been trying to do it for a long time both via maven-compiler-plugin and properties... to no success, even though I was refreshing Maven after making changes to pom.xml. Finally, I restarted the IDE .. and .. it works! I can compile..